# Does movement continue after an Opportunity Attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack

If a character moves away from a square adjacent to a monster, the monster gets an OA. Good.  What happens after the attack is resolved? Can the character continue moving?

So far, I've houseruled that if the attack misses, the character can continue his movement, but not if he is hit. I'd like to know if there's something official.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [Opportunity Action](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=119),

> Interrupts Target’s Action: An opportunity action takes place before the target finishes its action. After the opportunity attack, **the creature resumes its action**. If the target is reduced to 0 hit points or fewer by the opportunity attack, it can’t finish its action because it’s dead or dying.

A normal OA will *not* interrupt movement. Even if the creature is hit, it can continue it's movement as normal.

That said, it is *possible* to stop the movement, but you'd need a power or ability that explicitly says so. For example, the stance [Defend the Line](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=12664) would allow the fighter to slow the enemy on an OA. The creature would then only be able to move a total of 2 squares for his current move action. If he has already moved 2 or more squares, he stops in the square he provoked the OA from.

There's also the fighter's Combat Superiority which stops movement altogether.

> **Combat Superiority**
>
> You gain a bonus to opportunity attacks equal to your Wisdom modifier. An enemy struck by your opportunity attack stops moving, if a move provoked the attack. If it still has actions remaining, it can use them to resume moving.

Comment: Sure. By the time I get mine in, someone's done it better. :)

Comment: Agreed on this. Think about a Running Back. The character knows that they are breaking an engagement with a deadly threat, and they have plans to break out. The threat is going to try to stop them, but if they are still on their feet they are going to push through the pain and keep going. If they are not dead or disabled, they will smash through the line!

Comment: Here's a question for clarification. Do you treat each square of movement as though it were were a separate miniature action? So you move X squares, get interrupted, and then move the remainder of your movement from wherever you landed, if possible?

Answer (score 9):

PHB1 on p290 goes into detail on opportunity attacks. As far as I read it, unless an attack that is being used for the opportunity attack specifically mentions that it stops the character, then they can continue moving.

For example, the fighter's Combat Superiority ability reads

> An enemy struck by your opportunity attack stops moving, if a move provoked the attack. If it still has actions remaining, it can use them to resume moving.

Comment: Great minds think alike!

Comment: Haha! Indeed! +1 to yours sir =)

Comment: \*elegant bow\* and you as well

Answer (score 8):

The Compendium lists:

> Interrupts Target’s Action: An opportunity action takes place before the target finishes its action. After the opportunity attack, the creature resumes its action. If the target is reduced to 0 hit points or fewer by the opportunity attack, it can’t finish its action because it’s dead or dying.

Conceptually, the attack happens while they're moving - unless the attack does something to prevent the movement (dropping the target is listed, I'd also say adding the slowed or immobilized conditions would work as well), the target finishes the action after the response.

Comment: Indeed. It's interesting that the "immobilized" or "slowed" conditions wouldn't stop a ranged or area attack that provoked an OA. Of course, I left that kind of stuff out of the question :)

Comment: No, however Dazed would if the target had already taken a minor or move action during the turn. If no other actions had been taken dazed has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

As a DM I have sort of a house rule that seems to make sense.

If the creature or PC is attacking and provokes an opportunity attack we roll the opportunity attack and if the roll is a *Critical Hit* we stop the movement and allow them to use the rest of their actions or even an *Action Point* to finish out their turn, *if they have an action point*.

This has worked for my group for awhile now and I have seen other groups use this method in *Encounters* as well.

Comment: Whilst it's nice to see house rules, it's not an "answer" to the straight DnD 4e question