# Does a forced movement from an OA stop a movement action in progress?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat, movement, shift

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does movement continue after an Opportunity Attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8661/does-movement-continue-after-an-opportunity-attack)

I am in the process of creating a Druid, and an interesting opportunity came up.
I a creature moves away from me to prevent damage from Storm Spike, I can make an Attack of Opportunity. If this attack was, say, Savage Rend, I can slide them one square. Does this simply increase (or decrease, etc) the distance they have to walk to reach their destination by one? Or does it stop their movement in the space I planted them as if this was their location?

Example: A Human Bandit is engaged with me. I Storm Spike him, Wild Shape, and then move into position. On his turn, the Bandit decides to move away, moving 3 squares. I use Savage Rend for my melee basic, and slide him next to me. Does this end his movement, meaning he did not move 2 squares and takes Storm Spike damage?

Example 2: Same scenario, but assuming the Bandit only takes a move to step 2 squares away. Can I use my Savage Rend to slide him BACK one, thus making his movement end after 1 action and force the Storm Spike damage?

Thank you very much for your time and I hope someone can help me out!